# Any way to pass operators <, <>, >= into sql-query?

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2

I have such piece of program:

```py
if self.current_condition == 'comparison':
comparison_command = '''SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE {pkey} < %s'''
cur.execute(sql.SQL(comparison_command).format(
                    table=sql.Identifier(self.current_table),
                    pkey=sql.Identifier(self.current_columns[0].text())
                ), 
                (self.comp_value, )
           )
```

What I want to do is write '<' in command in the same way as {table} and {pkey}, that means I want to pass operators into command from variable. Can I do it?

[The face of the app looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j94BI.png)
A little bit more of code context. It's an app, that should get data from database by sql-request, that creates from interface. As you can see, there's a bit more operators than one to choose.

```
    def run_func(self):
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            host='localhost',
            database='1rl',
            user='postgres',
            password=passwor)
        cur = conn.cursor()

        if self.current_condition == 'comparison':
            comparison_command = '''SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE {pkey} < %s'''
            cur.execute(sql.SQL(comparison_command).format(table=sql.Identifier(self.current_table),
                                                           pkey=sql.Identifier(self.current_columns[0].text())),
                                                            (self.comp_value, ))
            print(cur.fetchall())

    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()


def display(self, i):
    self.list_of_conditions.setCurrentIndex(i)
    self.current_condition = self.all_conditions[i]
    print(self.current_condition)



def comp_value_changed(self):
    self.comp_value = self.value.text()

def comp_on_selected(self):
    sender = self.sender()
    self.comp_selec = sender.text()

def comparison_fun(self):
    layout = QFormLayout()
    compars = QHBoxLayout()

    for i in self.all_comparisons:
        temp = QRadioButton(i)
        temp.toggled.connect(self.comp_on_selected)
        compars.addWidget(temp)

    layout.addRow(QLabel('Operators'), compars)

    self.value = QLineEdit()
    self.value.textChanged.connect(self.comp_value_changed)
    layout.addRow("Value", self.value)

    rune = QPushButton('Run')
    rune.clicked.connect(self.run_func)
    layout.addRow(rune)
    self.comparison.setLayout(layout)
```

Comment: Placeholders in the SQL statement are for literal values only, not operators.  There might be some way to do what you want, if you can explain it better above.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I mean, that I want to pass operators from the variable, not from the code.

Comment: Can you give the code context on where that operator would come from? Would you have a variable that has something that indicates which one you need?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @trincot Yes, there is variable, that contents, what operator should be.

Comment: Can you point to the variable please? Which variable is it? And is its value the operator in the right syntax, or does it still need some translation, like from "gte" to ">=", or something like that. Your code shows a lot of other things, but not the actual operator values you are working with.

Comment: @trincot Oh, sorry, I didn't understand your question for the first time. It's `self.comp_selec`. It appears in `def comp_on_selected` and it comes just from the toggled radio button.

Comment: Does the user select the value from a radio button *in a web browser*? Is this also how they select the table and the column? Does your Python script run on the client or the server?

Comment: @trincot No, it isn't a web app. It uses only localhost and, to be honest, there's nothing more than unversity project, so the app works just on local computer and nothing else. But yes, the user also select the table and the column, in another widgets (QStackedWidget and QListWidget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string interpolation on `comparison_command`, use f-string notation, and double the existing braces to escape them:

```
comparison_command = f'SELECT * FROM {{table}} WHERE {{pkey}} {self.comp_selec} %s'
cur.execute(sql.SQL(comparison_command).format(
                    table=sql.Identifier(self.current_table),
                    pkey=sql.Identifier(self.current_columns[0].text())
                ), 
                (self.comp_value, )
           )
```

This assumes that `self.comp_selec` has the operator in the SQL syntax, i.e. it should be like "<", "<=", "=", ">=", ">", and not "==", "ge", "greater", ...etc.

I need to add the disclaimer about the risk of SQL injection. As I understand all of this runs on a local machine, a smart user could potentially tamper with the executable and make the SQL execute something harmful for the database or its security.

Comment: It gave me an error `Composed elements must be Composable, got '<' instead`, so I've tried to write `operator = sql.Composable(self.comp_selec)`, but it gives me empty strings and that's all...

Comment: Another attempt: getting it done before  `.SQL` is called.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to make string Composable before executing, but the result is the same. Maybe, I didn't get your point right...

Comment: Oh no, I mistyped when I was copying yout solution! I corrected it and now it works well! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Literal).`SQL` to pass in the operator:

```
comparison_command = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE {pkey} {op} %s").\
    format(table=sql.Identifier("test"), pkey=sql.Identifier("id"), op=sql.SQL(">"))

print(comparison_command.as_string(con))                                                                                                                                                                                
SELECT * FROM "test" WHERE "id" > %s

for op in [">", "<", "="]:
    comparison_command = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE {pkey} {op} %s").\
    format(table=sql.Identifier("test"), pkey=sql.Identifier("id"), op=sql.SQL(op))
    print(comparison_command.as_string(con))

SELECT * FROM "test" WHERE "id" > %s
SELECT * FROM "test" WHERE "id" < %s
SELECT * FROM "test" WHERE "id" = %s
```